# OGNL parse exception

Tags: struts-validation

Can anyone tell me what could have raised this error..?

```
[ognl.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 1
Was expecting one of:
    ":" ...
    "not" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "~" ...
    "!" ...
    "(" ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "null" ...
    "#this" ...
    "#root" ...
    "#" ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    "@" ...
    "new" ...
    <IDENT> ...
    <DYNAMIC_SUBSCRIPT> ...
    "\'" ...
    "`" ...
    "\"" ...
    <INT_LITERAL> ...
    <FLT_LITERAL> ...
    ]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Parse error for certain **`parameter`**, you can find out which parameter is invalid by checking the submitted URL.

**Try :** 

- Correct the invalid `name` of the parameter
- Or, the following example might be a solution / give you an idea :

**struts.xml**

```
<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
        <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,jquery\..*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</interceptor-stack>
```

**[Excluding parameters](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/parameters-interceptor.html)**

This interceptor can be forced to ignored parameters, by setting its excludeParams attribute. This attribute accepts a comma separated list of regular expressions. When any of these expressions match the name of a parameter, such parameter will be ignored by the interceptor.